# Is there a leader key function like vim or a hotstring function like autohotkey in xbindkeys?

Tags: linux, vim, autohotkey

I want to implement one of the functions below with xbindkeys:

Leader key function like vim:

```
noremap <leader>1 iabc
```

Or hotstring function like autohotkey:

```
::\1::
    msgbox haha
return
```

I have googled the key words "xbindkeys leader", but there are no right answers.

Anybody have any ideas? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the `<leader>` in Vim is just a convenient "constant" that's only expanded by Vim **when the mapping is defined**. It's not a special key *at all*.

Comment: Thx for your explaination anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Took me nearly two searches to undesrtand the question, the leader key will be the promise that another key comes, I don't use vim. Short  and late answer, you can via scripting. Take a look to [doubleclick_delayed](https://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html#utilities).

More long answer: If you separate the two clicks from the script to two keys you already have one shortcut, if you manage to have a parameter that receives the second key then it's solved.

In case there was no previous leader key then the script has to do nothing but keep the key, obviously that is a extra step you dont always want.

I did something similar for my mouse (similar respect the delay) spliting in one call when the button is pressed and another when is released I called [hold_n_release_multicommand](https://github.com/TapiaX/hold_n_release_multicommand), but hold is not needed if they are different keys